# Using ConcurrentDictionary in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

I wrote following Code

```
public static class QuizSessionBL
    {
        #region Private Data

        private static ConcurrentDictionary<int, QuizData> _data = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, QuizData>();

        #endregion

        #region Public Methods

        public static void AddOrUpdate(QuizData pQuizData)
        {
            _data.AddOrUpdate(pQuizData.Quiz.QuizId, pQuizData,
            (key, existingVal) =>
            {
                return existingVal;
            });
        }

        public static bool Retrieve(int pQuizId, out QuizData pQuizData)
        {
            return _data.TryGetValue(pQuizId, out pQuizData);
        }

        public static void Remove(int pQuizId)
        {
            QuizData qd;
            _data.TryRemove(pQuizId, out qd);
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

My objectives are :

1. To Provide in memory Quiz Data to student without query DB everytime.
2. AddOrUpdate() method will be called by Quiz Administrator when he starts quiz
3. Remove() method will be called by administrator when he wants to close quiz.

Ex If 30 students of 3 course (10 of each course ) , calls Retrieve() method concurrently, then _data collection should have only 3 entries , one for each course.

So basically I want to know the efficiency of above code , Or Should I add something more to it. I am expecting answer in terms of logic/concept rather than discussion.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood. Where is DB access? This code is just a static wrapper over concurrent dictionary. Are you talking about performance of underlying concurrent dictionary? Is `QuizData` internally thread safe?

Comment: No Internally QuizData is not thread safe , but we need not to care about the thread safety of QuizData because of ConcurrentDictionary. Code of DB Layer is not here because this class is part of Business Layer Only and it's methods will get called through UI layer and Da ta layer through some mechanism later

Comment: "we need not to care about the thread safety of QuizData because of ConcurrentDictionary" is a concern. Are you saying two different threads can't query the dictionary for same key?

Comment: ConcurrentDictionary is already thread safe , we can use ConcurrentDictionary with any thread-unsafe object to make it thread safe.

Comment: No. This assumption is wrong. Access to dictionary is tread safe, but access to stored object is not. If you have two threads with same key asking dictionary to get the object, it will return reference to same object and bad things will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Your example looks good in that there will only ever by 1 item with the same ID in the dictionary. BUT ConcurrentDictionary will only makes sure that adding/removing is threadsafe. If two students get the same QuizData object and modify it they will be overwriting each other unless there is threadsafety within/around each QuizData object.

Comment: 1.  Students will not going to modify the QuizData object .           2.  When I will extract a item from collection then I will fetch by copying(cloning) it rather getting refeence of original item.